# Rails passing params from index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app where I list records on an index page.
One of the columns is:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "event_ids[]", event.id %></td>
```

I have a button on the bottom of the index page:

```
<%= link_to 'Submit ', addinvtimes_invtimes_path, :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

I wanted this code to run in the invtimes controller:

```
   def addinvtimes
    if params[:event_ids] != nil
      params[:event_ids].each do |i|
        newinvtime = Invtime.new(
            linetype_id: 1,
            invoice_id: @invoice.id,
            event_id: i.to_i
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

But, `params[:event_ids]` is nil even if several boxes are checked.

Can't you submit params using an index page?  Does it have to be a form?

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE 1

I tried passing the array `event_ids[]` in the call:

```
<%= link_to 'Submit ', addinvtimes_invtimes_path(:workorder_id => @workorder, :event_ids[] => event_ids[]), :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

But, got:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
```

I just need the array `event_ids[]` to be accessible in the controller code `addinvtimes`.

UPDATE2

All I'm trying to do is list a bunch of records and include a checkbox column.  Then in the controller get back a list of ids for the rows that were checked.

Comment: Yes, these need to be wrapped in a form unless you use Javascript to capture someone clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the page (index, new, edit, etc.) does not affect the ability to submit data, however, a form is required if you want to post data using pure HTML to be in the params hash.

UPDATE1:

As for the update, adding :event_ids[] as a parameter to the link will only add it as a querystring parameter to the link, assigning it the value of event_ids[] at the time the view is parsed. Changes to the checkboxes in the html will not be reflected in the querystring. I think, the easiest way would be to just wrap the checkboxes and the submit into a form tag and let it post the data to your controller action.

Oh, and I just saw, the wrong number of arguments error resulted in calling [] on event_ids without an index. I wasn't sure, but apparently you can't have [] in variable names.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try using a form tag

Comment: I tried `<%= form_tag do %>` - but, `params[:event_ids]` is still nil.

Comment: I got it working - used `<%= simple_form_for :invtime, :url => url_for(:action => 'addinvtimes', :controller => 'invtimes'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>`